# How to empty the message in a text area with jquery?

Tags: jquery

--UPDATED--

I want to empty message in a textarea in callback.

Can anyone tell me how to empty it please?

I tried `$("#message").empty()`, but it does not empty it.

```
 <form method="post" id="form" action="index.php/admin/messages/insertShoutBox">        
    <input name="user" id="nick" value="admin" type="hidden">
    <p class="messagelabel"><label class="messagelabel">Message</label>
    <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="2" cols="40"></textarea>
    <input disabled="disabled" id="send" value="Sending..." type="submit"></p>          
</form>
```

Full code

```
 $("#form").submit(function(){
    if(checkForm()){
        var nick = inputUser.attr("value");
        var message = inputMessage.attr("value");
        //we deactivate submit button while sending
        $("#send").attr({ disabled:true, value:"Sending..." });
        $("#send").blur();
        //send the post to shoutbox.php
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", 
            url: "index.php/admin/dashboard/insertShoutBox", 
            data: $('#form').serialize(),
            complete: function(data){
                messageList.html(data.responseText);
                updateShoutbox();
                 $('#message').val('').empty();
                //reactivate the send button        
                $("#send").attr({ disabled:false, value:"SUBMIT !" });
            }
         });
    }
    else alert("Please fill all fields!");
    //we prevent the refresh of the page after submitting the form
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 127, accepted):

```js
$('#message').val('');
```

**Explanation** (from @BalusC):

`textarea` is an `input` element with a value. You actually want to "empty" the value. So as for every other `input` element (`input`, `select`, `textarea`) you need to use `element.val('');`.

Also see [docs](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Comment: I tried  $('#message').val('').empty(); but did not empty it.

Comment: `empty()` does not apply here, that is only used to remove child nodes from an element. `val('')` is correct, so if it is not working, you need to post more code, because it sounds like that specific line is not being called at all

Comment: forget empty(), just use this answer, which sets the value (i.e. contents) of the textarea to nothing.

Comment: Explanation: `textarea` is an **input** element with a *value*. You actually want to "empty" the *value*. So as for every other input element (`input`, `select`, `textarea`) you need to use `element.val('');`. Also see http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/val

Comment: note: setting the value as null does not work (I thought it would and wanted to put this here for others)

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#message').html('');
```

You can use this method too. Because everything between the open and close tag of textarea is html code.

Comment: .html('') or .text('') both didn't work for me. Only .val('') works.

Answer (score 2):

.html(''). was the only method that solved it for me.

Answer (score 2):

for set empty all input such textarea select and input run this code:

```
$('#message').val('').change();
```

Answer (score 0):

//since you are using AJAX, I believe that you can't rely in here with the submit
 //empty the action, you can include charset utf-8 as jQuery POST method uses that as well I think

**HTML**

```
<input name="user" id="nick" value="admin" type="hidden">

<p class="messagelabel"><label class="messagelabel">Message</label>

<textarea id="message" name="message" rows="2" cols="40"></textarea>

<input disabled="disabled" id="send" value="Sending..." type="submit">
```

**JAVACRIPT**

```
                            //reset the form to it's original state
            $.fn.reset = function () {

                              $(this).each (function() { 
                                this.reset();
                                 });
                                                    //any logic that you want to add besides the regular javascript reset
                                                /*$("select#select2").multiselect('refresh');    
                                                $("select").multiselect('destroy');
                                                redo();
                                                */
                            }


//start of jquery based function
 jQuery(function($)
 {
 //useful variable definitions




var page_action = 'index.php/admin/messages/insertShoutBox';

 var the_form_click=$("#form input[type='submit']");

 //useful in case that we want to make reference to it and update

 var just_the_form=$('#form');

 //bind to the events instead of the submit action


the_form_click.on('click keypress', function(event){
```

//original code, removed the submit event handler.. 
 //$("#form").submit(function(){

```
if(checkForm()){

    //var nick = inputUser.attr("value");
    //var message = inputMessage.attr("value");

    //seems more adequate for your form, not tested
    var nick = $('#form input[type="text"]:first').attr('value');
    var message = $('#form input[type="textarea"]').attr('value');


    //we deactivate submit button while sending
     //$("#send").attr({ disabled:true, value:"Sending..." });

    //This is more convenient here, we remove the attribute disabled for the submit button and we change it's value

    the_form_click.removeAttr('disabled')
    //.val("Sending...");
    //not sure why this is here so lonely, when it's the same element.. instead trigger it to avoid any issues later
    .val("Sending...").trigger('blur');


  //$("#send").blur();


    //send the post to shoutbox.php
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        //see you were calling it at the form, on submit, but it's here where you update the url
        //url: "index.php/admin/dashboard/insertShoutBox", 


        url: page_action,

        //data: $('#form').serialize(),
        //Serialize the form data
        data: just_the_form.serialize(),

       // complete: function(data){
       //on complete we should just instead use console log, but I;m using alert to test
       complete: function(data){
       alert('Hurray on Complete triggered with AJAX here');
       },
       success: function(data){
            messageList.html(data.responseText);
            updateShoutbox();

      var timeset='750';
                setTimeout(" just_the_form.reset(); ",timeset); 
                //reset the form once again, the send button will return to disable false, and value will be submit

             //$('#message').val('').empty();
            //maybe you want to reset the form instead????

            //reactivate the send button
            //$("#send").attr({ disabled:false, value:"SUBMIT !" });
        }
     });
}
else alert("Please fill all fields!");


//we prevent the refresh of the page after submitting the form
//return false;

//we prevented it by removing the action at the form and adding return false there instead

event.preventDefault();
});   //end of function

}); //end jQuery function

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A comment to *jarijira*

Well I have had many issues with .html and .empty() methods for inputs o. If the id represents an input and not another type of html selector like

or  use the .val() function to manipulate.

For example: this is the proper way to manipulate input values

```
<textarea class="form-control" id="someInput"></textarea>

$(document).ready(function () {
     var newVal='test'
     $('#someInput').val('') //clear input value
     $('#someInput').val(newVal) //override w/ the new value
     $('#someInput').val('test2) 
     newVal= $('#someInput').val(newVal) //get input value

}
```

For improper, but sometimes works
For example: this is the proper way to manipulate input values

```
<textarea class="form-control" id="someInput"></textarea>

$(document).ready(function () {
     var newVal='test'
     $('#someInput').html('') //clear input value
     $('#someInput').empty() //clear html inside of the id
     $('#someInput').html(newVal) //override the html inside of text area w/ string could be '<div>test3</div>
     really overriding with a string manipulates the value, but this is not the best practice as you do not put things besides strings or values inside of an input. 
     newVal= $('#someInput').val(newVal) //get input value

}
```

An issue that I had was I was using the $getJson method and I was indeed able to use .html calls to manipulate my inputs. However, whenever I had an error or fail on the getJSON I could no longer change my inputs using the .clear and .html calls. I could still return the .val(). After some experimentation and research I discovered that you should only use the .val() function to make changes to input fields.

Answer (score 0):

$("#message").prop("val","");  it works for me.

Answer (score -1):

Textareas & jquery are tricky, as they are specified by an input tag.
Be sure to specify:

```
$('textarea[name="content"]').val('');
```

instead of:

```
$('input[name="content"]').val('');
```

Comment: This selector is inaccurate. Elements do not magically change in reference. Remember specificity is important in selectors so locating a form element I would use the id, then just the name attribute if I had to. The more specific you get the faster the process will run.