# How to clear value in tejquery text editor using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, text-editor

I would like to ask you a question about tejquery text editor, I would like to clear data from text editor after Ajax respond success. I have tried to use code below but it still not work, so could anyone help me.

HTML :

```
<div class="container">
 <input type="text" class="website-header" />
 <textarea name="textarea" class="jqte-test website-desc"></textarea>
 <input type="button" name="bu" value="Save" id="btn-for-website-video-url" />  
</div>
```

Here is an jquery code with ajax :

```
$("#btn-for-website-video-url").on("click",function(){ 
    var website_desc   = $(".website-desc").val(); 
    var website_header = $(".website-header").val();

   $.ajax({
       url     : "php/respon_result.php",
       type    : "POST",
       dataType: "json",
       data    : { header : website_header , desc : website_desc },
       success : function(data){ 
          // clear data in text editor
         $('.website-desc').val('');
        },

        error : function(data){
                alert('Error log');
        }

}
```

Comment: check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078146/how-to-empty-the-message-in-a-text-area-with-jquery,

Comment: I've already used it, but it still not work. You can see this website of plugin I've used : http://jqueryte.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from their site [documentation](http://jqueryte.com/documentation) methods, you have to use [.jqteVal('')](http://jqueryte.com/documentation#method-jqteVal)

> This method using for changing to the value of the editor.

```
$(".website-desc").jqteVal('');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn-for-website-video-url").on("click",function(){ 
    $(".website-desc").val(" "); 

  });
});
```

Comment: I've already used it, but it still not work. You can see this website of plugin I've used : jqueryte.com –  samphors

Answer (score 0):

you can reset it  after checking the google chrome dev tools and getting the  class name of the div  that handles the html values :

```
   $('.jqte_editor').html(' ');
```

instead of :

```
      $('.you editor name').val(' ');
```

that worked form me

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$(".website-desc").html('');
```